# Is this Brzezinski quote real?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, political-history, russia, quotes

Various Russian websites attribute to [Brzezinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zbigniew_Brzezinski) the following quote:

> The new world order under U.S. hegemony was created against Russia at
>   the expense of Russia and on the ruins of Russia.

I am quoting it from an [article](http://myfutureamerica.org/?p=1838)  in English, which however reads as if it was painstakingly translated from Russian.

So - is this quote real or a fake?

Comment: The phrase "New World Order" raises a lot of flags for me. It generally has negative connotations in the USA. Pretty much the only time I've heard someone use it positively was professional Wrestling [heels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heel_(professional_wrestling)). IOW: Its a phrase cartoonish **fictional** bad guys use, not actual people. I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yeah, my own fakedar is also bleeping like crazy. But I was able to conclusively resolve this on my own.

Comment: Considering that Brzezinski had been out of any kind of power for a decade before the Ukraine and the post USSR Russia even existed, I don't see how any of his remarks should be taken as anything official or reflecting the policies of an opposition party.  Brz is a Democrat, speaking about a Republican administration.

Comment: @Oldcat - I could argue around that, but honestly we don't even know the context of this quote. It could be about the post WWII regime, it could be about the post Cold War regime, it could be entirely about economics, it could be about the caviar industry, or entirely made up.

Comment: I had an answer to this question. In it I provided two links, one of which users did not like, so is still being downvoted (without explanation actually). As there is now a different answer referencing the same speech I did, I am removing my answer, as I am unwilling to take any more (continuing) reputation hits for what I assume was a link to an unacceptable site. Sorry.

Comment: @Oldcat: Brz is an extremely hawkish Democrat, and was still being quoted regularly for opinion on Russia policy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.ji.lviv.ua/n14texts/brzez-pr.htm
Here is an original Brzezinski speech on ceremony of giving him the status of honorary citizen of Lviv (in ukrainian). There's no word about the U.S. hegemony and no word against Russia, only about Ukraine as outpost of the West, [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=uk&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ji.lviv.ua%2Fn14texts%2Fbrzez-pr.htm&edit-text=) will help you;)

Answer (score 8):

It is pretty hard to prove a negative in the social sciences (consider how many people still believe the [The Protocols of the Elders of Zion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Protocols_of_the_Elders_of_Zion) hoax!) but I would bet that Brzezinski never said anything like that - this is an extremely stupid thing to say, and I don't think he is *that* stupid.

The "New world order" was the expression used by Bush-1 to describe the era of collaboration with Russia in the aftermath of the decline of communism, especially around the [Gulf War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_War). 
The excitement about the friendly relationships with Russia was quite genuine.

Comment: What this answer is really missing IMHO is the fact that 99% of the time when you hear the phrase "New World Order" used, it is not in that Bush-1 sense, but rather referring to [a Conspiracy Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_World_Order_%28conspiracy_theory%29) prevalent in the US in far right circles.

Comment: @T.E.D.: This specific incarnation of the phrase comes out of the Russian loonies, not the American ones, and harks back to the Hitler's use of the expression.

Comment: @sds the phrase "new world order" has been used many times to hint at obscure "conspiracies" by "right wing radicals" or "capitalists" to "secretly control the world". Bush Sr. used it in a different context, probably jokingly, and ever since the conspiracy theorists are calling it "illuminati" and other nonsense.

Comment: "* I don't think he is that stupid*" Considering that we are talking about someone who openly bragged about his great idea of mobilizing Islamic fundamentalism against the Soviet Union, I think it is safe to say that he is *that* stupid. It doesn't mean, of course, that he said the quote, but it is the kind of thing that one would expect from this genius.

Comment: @LuísHenrique: "_idea of mobilizing Islamic fundamentalism against the Soviet Union_" - brilliant idea: let bad guys fight each other. Of maybe you are insinuating that he _created_ islamism?!

Answer (score -2):

Here:
http://www.duel.ru/199905/?5_2_3

The speech on accepting the status of 'honorary citizen of Lviv' 1999

"Новый мировой порядок при гегемонии США создается против России, за счет России и на обломках России."

literally: The new world order under U.S. hegemony is being created against Russia at the expense of Russia and on the ruins of Russia.

Comment: Duel is a notorious Russian newspaper which peddles conspiracy theories, neo-Stalinist drivel and other similar wares. I don't think this can be a reliable source for the question.

Comment: Moreover, this particular lie has already been debunked in the accepted answer.